# Making some parser rules case-insensitive in antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am wrting a small csharp console application which reads text from console, do some some manipulations and returns a string. For this, I am using Antlr. The  grammar file is shown below.

```
    grammar test;
options {

  language = CSharp2;
  output = AST;
}
start returns [String res]: expression EOF
{ 
$res=$expression.res;  
} ;

expression returns [String res]
: Identifier  {$res=$Identifier.text}
|Num {$res=$num.text;
|function {$res=function.res}
;

function: 'left'  '( Identifier ')'{some code here}
        | 'right' '( Identifier ')'{some code here}
        |..........
         ;
Num : (Minus)?('0'..'9')+   ;
Identifier  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'\\'|'/'|'_'|':'|';'|'?'|'.'|'0'..'9')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'\\'|'/'|'_'|':'|';'|'.'|'?'|'0'..'9')*;
```

I have several such functions which do some string manipulations. Now, I want Antlr to identify these function names irrespective of case.  At present, it accepts only lower case letters as function names like.. upper(asdf). I cannot convert every token to lower case in my application as it changes the case of Identifiers also. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply define the appropriate token.  So, for the code above:

```
function : Left  '(' Identifier ')' {some code here}
         | ..........
         ;

Left : ('l'|'L')('e'|'E')('f'|'F')('t'|'T');
```

or, if you are sure you want have cases like `lEfT`:

```
function : Left  '(' Identifier ')' {some code here}
         | ..........
         ;

Left : ('left'|'LEFT');
```

Comment: You are correct, hence I removed the "guess"-part of your answer.

Comment: ok, thanks (i was wondering if tokens were defined using a regexp that could have a "caseless" flag, but didn't turn up anything on a search).

Comment: ANTLR 2 had that option (case insensitive lexer matching), but ANTLR 3 doesn't.

Comment: I have around 30 functions. I have to define Caps and small letters for each function separately .. correct ?

Comment: yes, that is what Bart's comment confirms (well, obviously it would be simpler to write a little program to do the work for you).

Answer (score 4):

[The standard way](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2687342) for case-insensitivity is

```
LEFT : [Ll] [Ee] [Ff] [Tt];
```

If all rules are case-insensitive, then

1. Create your grammar with **lowercase only**
2. Before passing the string to be compiled to the lexer, make the string in **lower case**

Answer (score -1):

You can use 
    option
    {
        caseSensitive=false
    }
to maintain a case insensitive lexer

Comment: Error `illegal option caseSensitive`

Comment: As of 4.9.4, soon to be released, we will support a [caseInsensitive](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/options.md#caseinsensitive) option